# Magento SOAP V2 error (catalogInventoryStockItemList)

Tags: c#, .net, api, magento, soap

I have an array with some products SKU called "items_estoque", which I fill in a loop from a specific DataTable called "dt":

```
Dim items_estoque(0) As String
For Each linha As DataRow In dt.Rows
   If Not IsDBNull(linha("codigo_magento")) Then
       i += 1
       ReDim Preserve items_estoque(i)
       items_estoque(i) = linha("codigo_magento")
   End If
Next
```

I then call the Magento API using the "**catalogInventoryStockItemList**" function:

```
Dim estoque = magentoV2_servico.catalogInventoryStockItemList(magentoV2_sessao, items_estoque)
For Each item As MagentoV2_Temp.catalogInventoryStockItemEntity In estoque
    'Do stuff
Next
```

And almost everytime I do this, I get an undefined error, independet of the SKU or array length. [This is an example of the array content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOycn.jpg)

The weird thing is that, if I before trying to get those two specific products from the example, make a random call using "**catalogProductList**", like (`Dim produtos = magentoV2_servico.catalogProductList(magentoV2_sessao, filters, "")`), [I can then normaly go back to that same "**catalogInventoryStockItemList**" function and it will work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idTAV.jpg)

Why does that happen and, please, how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, forget about it, it turns out it was just a wrong variable in my login parameters (that took me one and a half days to find).
I'll leave the question here anyway because it's a little hard to find material about this API around

Comment: there is no much support for c#